# Запятая между однородными членами (определениями)

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ответ на вопрос.

> Всё это: и картины, и письменный стол, и мягкие, потертые кожаные кресла - показалось ему чужим и ненужным.

Почему после слова *мягкие* стоит запятая？Ведь определения *мягкие*, *кожаные* и *потертые* характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, разве нет？

Answer (score 3):

*Всё это: и картины, и письменный стол, и мягкие, потертые кожаные кресла — показалось ему чужим и ненужным.*

Мы имеем три определения. Первые два определения (мягкие и потертые) являются качественными:  они однородны между собой, так как обозначают **сближенные признаки**, и неоднородны по отношению к третьему относительному определению (кожаный).

О сближенных признаках

В этом случае  определения  являются контекстуальными синонимами: крепкий, благополучный человек. Сближение признаков происходит в конкретном тексте из-за причинно-следственной связи или наличия метафоры:  Стояла тёмная, безлунная ночь (тёмная, так как безлунная). По обеим  сторонам дороги неподвижно стоят старые, печальные берёзы.

У Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

3) если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.): В небе таяло одно маленькое, золотистое облачко (М. Г.) — внешний вид;

***Мягкие, потертые:*** качественные прилагательные обозначают сближенные признаки, так как создают обобщенный образ предмета (его внешний вид).

**Посмотрела текст:** Все это: и картины, и книги, и **любимый** письменный стол, и мягкие, потертые кожаные кресла – показалось ему чужим и ненужным. (Чаковский А.Б. Блокада).

В вопросе было пропущено единственное слово — **любимый**, но оно здесь очень важно. Именно оно создает образ уютного, любимого уголка, где автор, вероятно, любил проводить время за чтением книг, сидя в мягком кресле (поэтому оно потертое). Это и есть причина (семантическая, смысловая) сближения двух разных определений (мягкий, потертый).

Кроме того, есть еще причина "структурная": в этом предложении сложно прочитать длинный неоднородный ряд из трех определений в одну фразу (а это нужно будет сделать при отсутствии запятых:  мягкие потертые кожаные кресла),  так как в нем уже есть другие однородные члены, требующие перечисления.

Comment: *Стояла темная_безлунная ночь* – вполне возможно и не ставить запятую. А уж маленькое золотистое – тем паче. Тут явно скорее нет, чем да. Можно и ошибкой счесть. "Маленькое" относится не к "облачку", а к "золотистому облачку".

Comment: Это вопросы к Розенталю, я его только цитирую. Также следует учитывать, что сближение может быть авторским. Но вот "светлой безлунной ночи" скорее не бывает, поэтому два определения раскрывают одну тему и  запятая ставится.

Comment: Сколько угодно бывает - про белые ночи не слыхали?

Comment: Безусловно, да. слышала.  Но я не думаю, что можно сказать так: стояла светлая безлунная ночь, а речь идет именно об этом (является ли "темная" определением к "безлунной ночи"). Кстати, многие писатели использовали эту  пару определений, причем как кому нравится. Вот А. Куприн: Просыпаешься среди темной, безлунной, мартовской ночи и сначала никак не можешь сообразить, где ты находишься.  Как вы думаете, здесь нужны две запятые?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Одна или ни одной.

Comment: Да, спасибо, мне тоже кажется, что одна запятая лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как с разных... Они характеризуют поверхность. А главное – союз И прекрасно вставляется между "мягкими" и "потертыми". Значит, однородные члены.

Comment: Интуиция подсказывает, что запятая нужна, но Ваша аргументация хромает: кожаные тоже характеризует поверхность.

Comment: *А главное – союз И прекрасно вставляется между "мягкими" и "потёртыми". Значит, однородные члены.* Что тут хромает?

Comment: Кстати, запятую можно и не ставить. Но три неоднородных определения подряд встречаются очень редко.

Comment: "Они характеризуют поверхность" — "хромающая" аргументация,  "союз И прекрасно вставляется" — совсем не аргумент.

Comment: Как это не аргумент? Это один из самых главных аргументов.

Comment: Как Вы объективно определяете, есть ли возможность вставить союз? Сравнивая ширину союза с размером пробела между словами?

Comment: "Три неоднородных определения подряд встречаются очень редко" Утверждение верное, но не помогает решить задачу.  "Мягкие синие кожаные кресла" — тут никак нельзя поставить запятую, а у нас можно. Вопрос, как это аргументировать.

Comment: *>> Как Вы объективно определяете, есть ли возможность вставить союз?* Затрудняюсь в двух словах. Но можно, согласитесь. Главное ведь правильно определить – можно или нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Интуиция подсказывает, что запятая нужна, но с агрументацией проблема. Попробую предложить такое суждение: *кожаные кресла* — объективная реальность, *мягкие* и *потертые* — оценочные суждения, поэтому эти два определения однородны.