# Нужна ли запятая: Петя был теперь красивый, румяный(,) пятнадцатилетний мальчик

Tags: однородные-члены

Какая пунктуация верна и соответствует авторскому варианту:

а) У Розенталя: Петя был теперь красивый, румяный, пятнадцатилетний мальчик. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

б) Из публикуемых текстов в Интернете: Петя был теперь красивый, румяный пятнадцатилетний мальчик.

Comment: Нацкорус: Петя был теперь красивый, румяный пятнадцатилетний мальчик с толстыми, красными губами, похожий на Наташу. [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том третий (1867-1869)]

Comment: У Розенталя запятая, а у Толстого, похоже, ее нет.

Comment: Значит, вариант у Розенталя неверный? Как это объяснить? Как отличить однородные отношения от неоднородных?

Comment: Не мне судить Розенталя. Как отличить? Возвращаемся к вопросу: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445126/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8